# override <%@ Page "ValidateRequest="false" /> in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, configuration, web-config

`ValidateRequest="false"` is set in my asp.net web forms. As the project has around 500 pages, I need to override it from a single place.

But if I set `ValidateRequest="true"` from the `web.config` file, it will not work because the web forms have `ValidateRequest` set to `"false"`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Press CTRL + SHIFT + F and replace all `ValidateRequest="false"` to `ValidateRequest="true"` in Entire Solution.

Comment: Thanks Ali for your feedback. As the project is live project it is very time consuming to change all pages in server. looking for a solution to override it from a single place.

Comment: `ValidateRequestMode` can be changed via  code behind. But I don't think that's a good solution to do it by code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validaterequestmode(v=vs.110).aspx

I think It was a mistake long time a go to set `ValidateRequest` page by page because I could be globally set in the `web.config`.